# Selectbox > get values from other class (symfony2)

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, builder

I'm new to Symfony2 and have a question. I've succeeded in creating a form and getting values from another table in my selectbox.

But when I want to save the form, it gives an error.

This is my code of the builder:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('userId', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
            'label' => 'Select user',                        
        ))
        ->add('title')
        ->add('timestamp')
        ->add('text')
    ;
}
```

It all shows exactly the way I want it to show, but when I save I get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class AppBundle\Entity\User could not be converted to string
```

Which totally makes sense, because apparently the form doesn't submit the value of the selectbox, but gives the entire object in return.

```
private 'userId' => 
        object(AppBundle\Entity\User)[852]
          ...
```

So my question is: how do I get the correct value to be posted? (the ID of the user, instead of the object).

This is probably a really noobish question, but i'm new to Symfony, so please be gentle :-)

Thanks.

Jonathan

Comment: Can you add your user entity ? Maybe you miss the mapping

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a form field error, probably `entity` field is getting correct user object (it is intended to be), but you're using that value as a string somewhere else. Check your action or services (if you're calling them), or better look at the stacktrace returned by the error (profiler or default exception page can display it)

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the object you are creating a form for does not have a relationship mapping with Entity/User, in which case the error makes sense. If you fix the mapping, the save will work ok. In the database only the id will be saved but it will be a foreign key of User. Something like:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;
```

Or if you have serious reasons to save only the ID of the object you have to use data transformers so that you save only a certain piece of info (ID in your case) and not the object.

See: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html